# How to make a new thread and terminate it after some time has elapsed?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++

The deal is:

I want to create a thread that works similarly to executing a new .exe in Windows, so if that program (new thread) crashes or goes into infinite loop: it will be killed gracefully (after the time limit exceeded or when it crashed) and all resources freed properly.

And when that thread has succeeded, i would like to be able to modify some global variable which could have some data in it, such as a list of files for example. That is why i cant just execute external executable from Windows, since i cant access the variables inside the function that got executed into the new thread.

**Edit:** Clarified the problem a lot more.

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject` will not terminate the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thread is not some sort of magical object that can be made to do things. It is a separate path of execution through your code. Your code cannot be made to jump arbitrarily around its codebase unless you specifically program it to do so. And even then, it can only be done within the rules of C++ (ie: calling functions).

You cannot kill a thread because killing a thread would utterly wreck some of the most fundamental assumptions a programmer makes. You would now have to take into account the possibility that the next line doesn't execute for reasons that you can neither predict nor prevent.

This isn't like exception handling, where C++ specifically requires destructors to be called, and you have the ability to catch exceptions and do special cleanup. You're talking about executing one piece of code, then suddenly ending the execution of that entire call-stack. That's not going to work.

The reason that web browsers moved from a "thread-per-tab" to "process-per-tab" model is exactly this: because *processes* can be terminated without leaving the other processes in an unknown state. What you need is to use processes instead of threads.

When the process finishes and sets it's data, you need to use some inter-process communication system to read that data (I like Boost.Interprocess myself). It won't look like a regular C++ global variable, but you shouldn't have a problem with reading it. This way, you can effectively kill the process if it's taking too long, and your program will remain in a reasonable state.

Answer (score 3):

The  thread will already run after calling `CreateThread`.

`WaitForSingleObject` is not necessary (unless you really want to wait for the thread to finish); but it will not "force-quit" the thread; in fact, force-quitting - even if it might be possible - is never such a good idea; you might e.g. leave resources opened or otherwise leave your application in a state which is no good.

Comment: Oh, the purpose was to quit the thread after some time, so it doesnt keep running forever if some bug appears etc. Is that possible?

Comment: You should check up on information how windows Threads can communicate with each other; you could e.g. use Signals to do what you want. If some bug appears, and you just terminate the thread, however, there's no saying if the thread hasn't done anything stupid anway (e.g. garbled up the applications memory), so I guess you shouldn't overly concern yourself with such things, unless you see that it's absolutely necessary (which I'd have a hard time believing).

Comment: i see, i guess it probably wont hang, but i always think of every possibility to fail. at this moment i could go without the termination check though, but i still am not 100% sure there is no chance of failing... may you link to those so called Signals which i can use to terminate the thread after some time limit exceeded?

Comment: That's the thing, these events (sorry, my mistake, they're called events, not signals) can be used for still responding threads to communicate with each other (e.g. the main thread and the created one), but they're not suited for terminating a non-responsive thread!

Comment: isnt there any other way to do new thread that will safely free resources, kinda like clicking new .exe and when it crashes Windows will automatically free resources for it too? (i think)

Comment: If the work you want to do is really decoupled (meaning not much shared data), you could simply start a child process (an .exe, as you said); and such a child process could be easier "killed" I guess, and also wouldn't make as much problems as a rogue thread... haven't worked with child processes for a while though, so no guarantees here!

Comment: basically i only want to know if my thread succeeded in its job or not, so it must share some global bool variable or something. and perhaps any other data it will allocate when it has succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's what `WaitForSingleObject` does. It blocks until the object does something (in case of a thread it waits until the thread exits or the timeout elapses). What you need is

```
HANDLE thread = CreateThread(0, 0, do_stuff, NULL, 0, 0);
//rest of code that will run paralelly with your new thread.
WaitForSingleObject(thread, 4000); // wait 4 seconds or for the other thread to exit
```

Comment: I see, is it possible to create thread that will automatically quit after some time, so there is no chance it keeps running forever and thus take all my CPU power?

Comment: @Rookie. That thread itself should be responsible. It can, for example loop and exit the loop after the time has elapsed

Comment: yes, but what if there is a bug which makes that loop endless?

Comment: Rookie :) Debug it and find it :)

Comment: Indeed, but what if i didnt find the bug before sending the program to millions of people, and they all crash in very severe place... Instead i would prefer to tell the user that something gone wrong, than let it crash and piss off everyone. I am not god, so i cant write perfect code.

Comment: @Rookie: I fail to see how your scenario is specific to multithreading. In any case there can be an error which you, not god, failed to find. So how do threads and WaitForSingleObject come into play here?

Comment: just thought its good idea, since if its possible to exit a part of the program gracefull, then why not? ive seen it happening on other programs too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your worker thread to shut down after a period of time has elapsed, the best way to do that is to have the thread itself monitor the elapsed time in some way and then exit when the time is up.

Another way to do this is to monitor the elapsed time in the main thread or even a third, monitor type thread.  When the time has elapsed, [set an event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Your worker thread could [wait for this event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in it's main loop, and then exit when it has been raised.  These kinds of events, which are used to signal the thread to kill itself, are sometimes called "death events."  (Or at least, I call them that.)

Yet another way to do this is to [queue a user job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the worker thread, which needs to be in an [alterable wait state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The APC can then set some internal state variable which will trigger the death sequence in the thread when it resumes.

There is another method which I hesitate even mentioning, because it should only be used in extremely dire circumstances.  You can [kill the thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This is a very dangerous method akin to turning off your sink by detonating an atomic bomb.  You get the sink turned off, but there could be other unintended consequences as well.  Please don't do this unless you know exactly what you're doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to WaitForSingleObject.  That causes your parent thread to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `WaitForSingleObject` call?