# How to set a timeout in a function that is running in a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm doing a blocking communication with a server using a client. the function is running in a thread. I would like to set a time out functionality. I'm not using boost or something like that. I'm using windows threading library.

Here is the function that I want to set a time out functionality in it.

```
 bool S3W::IWFSData::WaitForCompletion(unsigned int timeout)
{

    if (m_Buffer)
    {
        while (!m_Buffer.IsEmpty())
        {
            unsigned int i = 0;
            char gfname[255]; // must be changed to SBuffer
            char minHeightArr[8], maxHeightArr[8], xArr[8], yArr[8];

            m_PingTime += timeout;

            if (m_PingTime > PONG_TIMEOUT)
            {
                m_PingTime = 0;
                return false;
            }

            while (m_Buffer[i] != '\0')
            {
                gfname[i] = m_Buffer[i];
                i++;
            }

            gfname[i] = '\0';

            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                minHeightArr[j] = m_Buffer[i++];
            }

            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                maxHeightArr[j] = m_Buffer[i++];
            }

            double minH = *(double*)minHeightArr;
            double maxH = *(double*)maxHeightArr;

            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                xArr[j] = m_Buffer[i++];
            }

            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                yArr[j] = m_Buffer[i++];
            }

            double x = *(double*)xArr;
            double y = *(double*)yArr;

            OGRFeature *poFeature = OGRFeature::CreateFeature(m_Layer->GetLayerDefn());

            if(poFeature)
            {
                poFeature->SetField("gfname", gfname);
                poFeature->SetField("minHeight", minH);
                poFeature->SetField("maxHeight", maxH);

                OGRPoint point;
                point.setX(x);
                point.setY(y);

                poFeature->SetGeometry(&point);


                if (m_Layer->CreateFeature(poFeature) != OGRERR_NONE)
                {
                    std::cout << "error inserting an area" << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Created a feature" << std::endl;
                }
            }

            OGRFeature::DestroyFeature(poFeature);

            m_Buffer.Cut(0, i);
        }
    } 

    return true;
}
```

There is a thread that is setting the data to the buffer

```
int S3W::ImplConnection::Thread(void * pData)
{
   SNet::SAutoLock lockReader(m_sLock);
    // RECEIVE DATA
   SNet::SBuffer buffer;
   m_data->SrvReceive(buffer);


  // Driver code for inserting data into the buffer in blocking communication 
   SNet::SAutoLock lockWriter(m_sLockWriter);
   m_data->SetData("ahmed", strlen("ahmed"));
   double minHeight = 10;
   double maxHeight = 11;
   double x = 4;
   double y = 2;
   char minHeightArr[sizeof(minHeight)];
   memcpy(&minHeightArr, &minHeight, sizeof(minHeight));


   char maxHeightArr[sizeof(maxHeight)];
   memcpy(&maxHeightArr, &maxHeight, sizeof(maxHeight));


   char xArr[sizeof(x)];
   memcpy(&xArr, &x, sizeof(x));


   char yArr[sizeof(y)];
   memcpy(&yArr, &y, sizeof(y));

   m_data->SetData(minHeightArr, sizeof(minHeightArr));
   m_data->SetData(maxHeightArr, sizeof(maxHeightArr));
   m_data->SetData(xArr, sizeof(xArr));
   m_data->SetData(yArr, sizeof(yArr));

   m_data->WaitForCompletion(1000);


    return LOOP_TIME;
}
```

Comment: why negating my question without saying a reason

Comment: It seems you have not the full function here (unbalanced block, no else part). BTW, which is the blocking part ?

Comment: @andre Just guessing: probably because you did not provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please edit your question to help us help you.

Comment: @Jarod42 The blocking is while(!m_Buffer.IsEmpty())

Comment: I have provided the full function here

Comment: its just getting data from the queue and send it to the server using createfeature

Comment: You want to break loop on timeout, or you want to do some operations?

Comment: There is a thread that sets and inserts the data into the queue, and wait for completion gets that data and sends it to the server using CreateFeature

Comment: @MartinZhai I want to break loop on timeout and return false meaning the operation is not successful

Comment: I would suggest you use SetTimer from msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user Can you show a sample code in my function ?

Comment: use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should not use threads for these purposes, because when terminating a thread like this, the process and the other threads could be left in an unknown state. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8478107/6451874) for the explanation.

Therefore, consider using procceses instead. Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) about opening processes in c++.

If you do want to use threads, you can exit the thread after the time passed.

Make a loop (as you have) that will `break` when some time has elapsed.

```
#include <ctime>

#define NUM_SECONDS_TO_WAIT 5

// outside your loop

std::time_t t1 = std::time(0);

// and in your while loop, each iteration:

std::time_t t2 = std::time(0);
if ((t2 - t1) >= NUM_SECONDS_TO_WAIT) 
{ 
    break; // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class member which holds a time stamp (when to timeout, set its value to `currentTime + intervalToTimeout`). In `WaitForCompletion()`, get current time and compare with the timeout time.

I assume in your code, `m_PingTime` is the time you start communication. You want to timeout after `1000` ms. What you need to do is, in `WaitForCompletion()`:

```
while (!m_Buffer.IsEmpty())
{
    ...
    long time = getCurrentTime();   // fake code
    if (m_PingTime + timeout < time)
    {
        m_PingTime = 0;
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you show a pseudo code please ? Should I use timeGetTime()?

Answer (score -1):

Here is something I did, if you want to implement it yourself:

```
clock_t startTime = clock();
clock_t timeElapsed;
double counter;
while(true){
    if(counter>=10){
        //do what you want upon timeout, in this case it is 10 secs
    }
    startTime = clock();
}
```